# deduct the follow group first element with the previous group first element

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to know whether is there a good and smart way by using pandas functions based on my above title?

I have codes:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': ['12:10:03.50', '12:10:02.50', '12:10:01.50', '2019/01/12 12:10:0.150', '2019/01/12 12:10:022.50', '2019/01/12 12:10:033.50'],
                        'number_of_people':[7, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                         'group': [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
```

1. I want to perform group 1(first element) - group previous(since it does not have then we can ignore)
2. group 2(first element) - group previous which is group 1(first element). Eg: 0-7 = -7 and so on until all group have been selected and performed the actions.

Expected output:

```
group 2 - group 1 = 0-7
group 3 - group 2 = 1- 0
```

thank you.

Comment: Expected output here would be helpful.

Comment: please show the expected output

Comment: But the definition already have expected output. Ok i will add,

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to subtract the number of people in two dataframes from each other. That can be done in a pretty pythonic way. Maybe it can be shorter but this would be my implementation:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': ['15:20:03', '1:10:02', '2:15:01', '2019/01/01 12:10:00', '2019/01/01 12:10:02', '12:10:03'], 'number_of_people':[27, 10, 40, 15, 10, 12], 'group': [19, 82, 72, 53, 24, 8]})
previous = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': ['2019/01/01 12:10:03', '2019/01/01 12:10:02', '2019/01/01 12:10:01', '12:10:00', '12:10:02', '12:10:03'], 'number_of_people':[7, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], 'group': [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

diff = pd.DataFrame({'number_of_people': [data['number_of_people'][i] - previous['number_of_people'][i] for i in range(len(data))]})

print(diff)
```

I assume you might want to do the same for the times. There's more to interpreting time strings than first meets the eye. If you consistently format the data in HH:MM:SS format for example it would be easier to do this. Of course you could use different time formats if you create a separate function to handle the different formats. Remember that deducting 12:00:00 from 2019/01/01 12:00:00 would result in 2019 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 seconds, where the desired result would (I assume) be 0 seconds. One way around this would be by stripping the YY/mm/dd part from the time string:

```
import pandas as pd

FORMAT = '%H:%M:%S'

def extractTime(time_str):
    time_str = time_str.split(' ')[-1]
    return sum(x * int(t) for x, t in zip([1, 60, 3600], reversed(time_str.split(":"))))

data = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': ['15:20:03', '1:10:02', '2:15:01', '2019/01/01 12:10:00', '2019/01/01 12:10:02', '12:10:03'], 'number_of_people':[27, 10, 40, 15, 10, 12], 'group': [19, 82, 72, 53, 24, 8]})
previous = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': ['2019/01/01 12:10:03', '2019/01/01 12:10:02', '2019/01/01 12:10:01', '12:10:00', '12:10:02', '12:10:03'], 'number_of_people':[7, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], 'group': [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

diff = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': [extractTime(data['datetime'][i]) - extractTime(previous['datetime'][i]) for i in range(len(data))]})

print(diff)
```